# How can I export/import my Firefox browsing history?

Tags: firefox

Transferring the places.sqlite file doesn't work for me due to broken compatibility in Firefox v55, so I need a workaround. Is there any way to export the history into a file and then import it in a different version of Firefox?

Comment: Simply transferring your Firefox user profile should be enough to transfer your browsing history.

Comment: @Ramhound, are you sure that you've read the question thoroughly?

Comment: I have indeed read your question thoroughly.  You might want to indicate what versions specifically you are attempting to use other then Firefox v55

Comment: @Ramhound, it's v54 -> v55 transition.

Comment: You may use [MZHistoryView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_history_view.html) from Nirsoft.